# Wordpress и даты

Tags: wordpress

А можно заставить wordpress склонять слова, чтобы выводил запись не "8 ноябрь" а "8 ноября"?
Или, если хотите, можно ли просто изменить значения, отвечающие за вывод месяцев, и вписать везде вместо Им.п. Род.п.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть специальный плагин для этого: MaxSite Russian Date

http://maxsite.org/page/russian-date